# ionicframework admob at the bottom of the view

Tags: admob, ionic-framework

I have this view code:

```
<ion-view view-title="Video divertenti">
  <ion-content on-swipe-left2="swipeLeft($index);" on-swipe-right2="swipeRight($index);">
      <ion-slide-box show-pager="false" on-slide-changed="cambiaVideo($index);">

      <ion-slide ng-repeat="item in lista track by item.nid">
          <div id="immaginiBox" >
              <div class="titolo">{{item.titolo}}</div>
              <blockquote class="desc" ng-show="item.desc != null"> {{item.desc}}</blockquote>
                <img id="thumb_{{$index}}" ng-click="playVideo($index)" style="width:100%;">
                <video style="display:none;" video-reset id="video_{{$index}}" ng-src2="{{item.videoT}}" controls="" width="100%" height="300px"></video>
          </div>
      </ion-slide>
      </ion-slide-box>
  </ion-content>

    <ion-footer-bar align-title="left" class="bar bar-footer">
        [MY TABS]
    </ion-footer-bar>

</ion-view>
```

and this code in my view's controller (for Admob):

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.loaded',function(eve) {
        if(AdMob) {
            AdMob.prepareInterstitial({adId: ApiEndpoint.admobid.interstitial, autoShow: false});

            AdMob.createBanner({
                    adId: ApiEndpoint.admobid.banner,
                    adSize: AdMob.AD_SIZE.BANNER,
                    bannerAtTop: false,
                },
                function () {

                    AdMob.requestAd(
                        {'isTesting': false},
                        function () {
                            AdMob.showAd(true);
                        },
                        function () {
                            console.log('failed to request ad');
                        }
                    );
                },
                function () {
                    console.log('failed to create banner view');
                }
            );
        }
    });
```

but I don't understand why admob is set at the top of the view and not at the bottom (this image is get from ios emulator):

[image: screehshot from emulator]

Comment: Which plugin are you using? Maybe you can try with this one if it's not the one you are using: https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova for me it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add following line:

```
AdMob.showBanner(AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER);
```

Comment: You might want to explain your answer a bit more. The question did say "I don't understand how...", a did not say "give a statement that..."